# Crawl all pages of a website and execute the same test against all of them in Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, katalon-studio

I have a basic common problem in the web framework I work with, that has the potential to affect many pages in the system.

Instead of hard-coding a list of pages to check, I was wondering if you can easily have katalon click all links on a page for example 2 levels deep, and execute the test there?

If not, one way around this could be to leverage the sitemap for the website and do it that way?

Basically I want "make sure that String XXXX" doesn't appear on any of the pages of my site.

Comment: This is likely a piece of the puzzle: https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Get+All+Links+On+Current+Page

Answer (score 0):

as you suggested there are 2 ways:

1. make a list from all `<a>` tags (a danger is that you get not only pages)
2. make a list of pages to check in excel (store their URI) and make data-driven test suite, or test case. examples are well documented on Katalon page